# A best practice for ngrx/redux action context

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, redux, ngrx

I try to find best practice for this scenario, but i don't find.

**problem:**
I don't want to repeat actions files, like in my example
home-todos.actions and sport-todos-actions, i want to use same to-dos.action file. and same reducer.

**example:**
I write a todo application for example, in this example you can see the problem if i dispatch an action with type 'ADD_TODO_ASYNC' it will dispatch in home(effects and reducer) , and sport(effects and reducer)

todos.actions.ts

```
const ADD_TODO_ASYNC = 'ADD TODO ASYNC';
const ADD_TODO_COMPLETE = 'ADD TODO COMPLETE';
const ADD_TODO_FAILD = 'AD TODO FAILD';

class addTodoComplete {
    type = ADD_TODO_COMPLETE;
}
class addTodoFaild {
    type = ADD_TODO_COMPLETE;
}

export type Actions = addTodoComplete | addTodoFaild;
```

sport.effects.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class SportTodosService {

    @Effect() ADD_TODO_ASYNC$ = this.actions$.ofType(TodosActionTypes.ADD_TODO_ASYNC)
    .map(toPayload)
    .swithMap( (todo: Todo) => this.api.addTodo(todo))
    .map((todo: Todo) => TodosActionTypes.addTodoComplete(todo))
    constructor(
        private actions$: Actions,
        private api: api
    ) { }

}
```

home.effects.ts

```
export class HomeTodosService {
    @Effect() ADD_TODO_ASYNC$ = this.actions$.ofType(TodosActionTypes.ADD_TODO_ASYNC)
        ...
    constructor(
        ...
    ) { }

}
```

reducer

```
function todosReducer(state, action: TodosActionTypes.Actions) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case TodosActionTypes.ADD_TODO_COMPLETE:
            return state;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
      AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
      StoreModule.forRoot({
        sport: todosReducer,
        home: todosReducer,
      }),
      EffectsModule.forRoot([
        SportTodosService
        HomeTodosService,
      ])
    ],
    providers: [
        api
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
  })
  export class AppModule { }
```

i try to understand what is the best practice for this scenario? 
write actions with context like 'HOME_ADD_TODO' & 'SPORT_ADD_TODO'?

or have official way?

if you know the solution, don't care if the solution is for redux or ngrx

thanks all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to understand this problem, you need think again on your app architecture.
in general reusable reducer/actions is incorrect.

why it's incorrect? in present view, it seem's awesome to write reusable reducer and actions, less boilerplate, and not "DRY". in example of your app. 'ADD_TO_DO' for home and sport are equal.

**but in future it will be dangerous**, thinking your boss/costumers need future in sports add_to_do. if you change the logic in the reusable reducer. your app will broke. (you can start patch your reusable reducer with if statements to get it work but if your app grow it will be not flexible/ readable/ maintenance ).

so yes it seems you need to write 2 reducers in this case, and 2 actions files. in present it fill equal but in the future it will be advantage and flexibale.

good luck!

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://blog.nrwl.io/ngrx-patterns-and-techniques-f46126e2b1e5) is a link with some of the patterns and practices for ngrx.

It's intended to work the way you've describe. `this.actions$` is an Observable, so it will emit wherever you use it. Since `TodosActionTypes.ADD_TODO_ASYNC` is the same type in both `home.effects.ts` and `sport.effects.ts`, it will emit in both places.

I'm not sure you can avoid having separate actions in your case, but you can decrease the amount of boilerplate code.

I would try something like this:

todos.actions.ts

```
abstract class addTodoComplete{
   constructor(readonly type: string){
      //rest of the behavior
   }
}
abstract class addTodoFailed{
   constructor(readonly type: string){
     //rest of the behavior
   }
}
```

todos.sport-actions.ts

```
const ADD_TODO = "[Sport] Add Todo";
const ADD_TODO_FAILED = "[Sport] Add Todo Failed";
class sportsAddTodoComplete extends addTodoComplete{
   constructor(){
      super(ADD_TODO);
      //rest of the behavior
   }
}
class sportsAddTodoFailed extends addTodoFailed{
   constructor(){
     super(ADD_TODO_FAILED);
      //rest of the behavior
   }
}
```

Same goes for home version.

Additionally, you would probably have separate `SportTodosActionTypes` and `HomeTodosActionTypes`.

You will not save yourself totally from "copy-paste", but it should help to some extent.

**EDIT:**

As for reducers, it is true that with this approach you will have to write two reducers, but it doesn't have to be a "copy-paste" work

sport.reducer.ts

```
import { todoReducer } from './reducer';

export function sportsTodoReducer(state, action: SportTodoActionTypes.Actions){
   todoReducer(state, action);
}
```

Similar goes for the `home` version.

Comment: i know they will emit both! i give it an example, to explain the problem!
i dont like your way because in this case i need to write todos reducer for sport actions and todos reducer for home actions

Comment: i know they will emit both! i give it an example, to explain the problem!
the action is not the problem, if we write unique action for context, in your solution i need 2 reducer

Comment: I have edited my post. You will have to have distinct actions for sport and home if you want to handle them separately. That means different actions, reducers, effects. You can only reduce the amount of copy pasted code.

Comment: nice it will work ,but the type will not work look again on the reducer.
and i need that type will work

Comment: It will if you extend that part as well. Try something like `TodoActionTypes.Actions = SportsTodoActionTypes.Actions | SportsTodoActionTypes.Actions`

Comment: in your extend way i dont reduce anything, look on your code every time i extend the abstract class but i write again class for every action , and const for every action!

Comment: and the reducer dont work because his expect to get 'ADD_TODO' string and not 'SPORT_TODO'

Answer (score 0):

**The solution in those cases is to use action Namespaces**

Action Constants act as unique identifiers for an action. Since there can be many actions in an application corresponding to different slices of the store, one way that we can guard our store from duplicate action logical failure is by using the concept of an Action Namespace. Check this out:

```
// todos.actions.ts
export const ADD_TODO = '[Home] Add Todo';
```

We simply append a namespace to the Action Constant that, ideally, corresponds to the name of the slice of the store that we are using - typically the name of the feature module you’re currently working on.

If we ever find ourselves debugging the application through logging actions, this namespace will make it clear what store slice and what action context we are troubleshooting, as we’ll see something like this (imagine we switch views from “Home” to “Sport”):

```
[Home] Add Todo
[Home] Add Todo Success
[Sport] Add Todo
[Sport] Add Todo Success
```

Check the [SOURCE](https://toddmotto.com/ngrx-store-actions-versus-action-creators) with more details

Comment: i know name spacing, but i fill that if i have 10 subject of todos in my app i will copy past the same actions? 
and in your solution, how i will handle it in one reducer?

Comment: i think you don't understand my problem! because in your way i need to write reducer and action twice